# Mysql Error: Table does not exist

Tags: mysql

When I try to login a user account on my Page, I get the following error:

> Table 'mysql.users' doesn't exist

I have checked that I have only one 'mysql' table and that is named `User` not `Users`.

Someone please guide me how to get rid of this error. **Can I change the Table name to "User"?**

Right now I have the following code:

```
query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='" . $mysqli-
real_escape_string($useroremail) . "' and `password`='" . md5($password) . "'
and `userlevel`='".($vendor==true ? 30 : 20)."'LIMIT 1;") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can i change the Table name to "User"?

Yes you can.

Try this.

```
 RENAME TABLE  `oldTableName` TO  `newTableName`

 RENAME TABLE  'Users' TO `User`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: after changing the names i get now this error: Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' .How i can change the code?: query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='"

Comment: oh.. i cant comment on that..